# How to write apostrophe after s in latex

Tags: latex

I have tried `\'` or `$'$` but the apostrophe after s does not appear in Latex. Do you know how can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried just ' (without anything added)?

Comment: yes. it does not show '.

Comment: Are you pressing the correct key in the keyboard? Some keyboards have an apostrophe key and an acute accent key.

Comment: This is off-topic and not reproducible.

Comment: I had a similar problem. The source of the problem was that I copy-pasted some text from Pages (MAC OS X editor) to some LaTeX editor. These two use some different symbols. A’a is how Pages gives it. A'a is how it should be to work in LaTeX.

Comment: I just had the same problem. As it has been discussed on other [pages](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=2130) the problem is that there are different characters for displaying an apostrophe on computers. When copying code form other editors, often the wrong kind is used.

What worked for me:  ' 
These don't work for me: ’ ´

Comment: @576i is right. Check this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69961/51344

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What do you mean?  Both kinds of apostrophes (sorry if that's not the correct typographical name) show up in both normal and math mode.  (Not an answer, but typesetting needed for question.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
A'B'C

A`B`C

$A'B'C$

$A`B`C$
\end{document}
```

(This would perhaps be a better question on the TeX stackexchange group.)

Comment: Thanks but assuming I have "ABC and D's" when I do $ABC and D's" it will be like "ABCandD's"

Comment: You need to distinguish between normal and math mode.  Which are the math variables?  You'd do something like $A$ and $B'$.  Or if it's in a deep math environment, $..... A\textit{ and }B'...$